# Loop on a data frame with considering the types of the values

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe, euclidean-distance

I have a large data set of coordinates and I want to calculate the Euclidean distance among them. The sample of that would be like this:

```
df <- data.frame("name" = c("a","b","c","a","e"), "type" = c("me","me","me","we", "we"), 
    "x" = c(64.044,63.722,64.359,65.373, 65.122),"y" = c(51.615,52.849,53.119,51.805,52.78),
    "z" = c(33.423,32.671,31.662,34.158,35.26))
```

> ```
> name  type    x   y   z
> a me  64.044  51.615  33.423
> b me  63.722  52.849  32.671
> c me  64.359  53.119  31.662
> d we  65.373  51.805  34.158
> e we  65.122  52.78   35.26
> ```

I want to calculate the Euclidean distance value among the rows of name column values that have different types. I write this code

```
require("distances")

for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  if(!(df$type[i]%in%df$type[i+1])){
    d <- distances(df[,3:5])
  }
}
```

However it was wrong. My ideal result should be like below in which d illustrates the distance between the name values:

```
    a.me    b.me    c.me    a.we    e.we
a.me    0   0   0   d   d
b.me    0   0   0   d   d
c.me    0   0   0   d   d
a.we    d   d   d   0   0
e.we    d   d   d   0   0
```

Besides, my data set is vary large and I think for is not the best choice. Anyone can help me on this issue?

Comment: Is this what you want: `dist(df[3:5], diag = TRUE, upper = TRUE)`?

Comment: @RuiBarradas No, I used distances function from "distances" package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a solution, but depending on the size of your data might be to much computational effort as first the whole dist-matrix is calculated and then only those which are needed selected:

```
dist_mat <- dist(df[3:5], diag = TRUE, upper = TRUE)
dist_mat <- as.matrix(dist_mat)
names_vec <- paste(df$name, df$type, sep = "_")
dimnames(dist_mat) <- list(names_vec, names_vec)

dist_mat <- 
  sapply(colnames(dist_mat), 
         function(x) ifelse(grepl(strsplit(x, "_")[[1]][2], 
                                  row.names(dist_mat)), NA, dist_mat[,x]))

row.names(dist_mat) <- names_vec

dist_mat
#          a_me     b_me     c_me     d_we     e_we
# a_me       NA       NA       NA 1.530544 2.427731
# b_me       NA       NA       NA 2.454976 2.944093
# c_me       NA       NA       NA 2.997467 3.693602
# d_we 1.530544 2.454976 2.997467       NA       NA
# e_we 2.427731 2.944093 3.693602       NA       NA
```

Comment: I appreciate your response. It is fine but as you said it is time consuming.

Answer (score 1):

This does the trick:

```
  df <- data.frame("name" = c("a","b","c","d","e"), "type" = c("me","me","me","we", "we"), 
                   "x" = c(64.044,63.722,64.359,65.373, 65.122),"y" = c(51.615,52.849,53.119,51.805,52.78),
                   "z" = c(33.423,32.671,31.662,34.158,35.26))

# lapply over the levels of the type
x <- lapply(levels(df$type), function(level) {
  # select the matching rows and columns and convert
  mat <- as.matrix(df[as.character(df$type) == level, 3:5])
  # names are set as row names for dist to use
  row.names(mat) <- paste(df$name[as.character(df$type) == level],
                          level,
                          sep = "_")
  # measuring the distance
  dist <- dist(mat, method = "euclidean", diag = TRUE, upper = TRUE)
  # converting distance to matrix
  as.matrix(dist)
})
# bind the list to one matrix
x <- plyr::rbind.fill.matrix(x)
# add rownames
row.names(x) <- colnames(x)
x

a_me     b_me     c_me     d_we     e_we
a_me 0.000000 1.480522 2.337170       NA       NA
b_me 1.480522 0.000000 1.223417       NA       NA
c_me 2.337170 1.223417 0.000000       NA       NA
d_we       NA       NA       NA 0.000000 1.492659
e_we       NA       NA       NA 1.492659 0.000000
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response, however it was not useful for my problem. I think since I have duplicate values in my name column.   I will improve my example to explain the issue better.

Comment: In other words, I need euclidean distances between member of each group as type regarding that a member can be exist in more than one group.

Comment: I think in that case it would be better to ask a new question. This does what you were describing as the optimal outcome. If you have duplicated column names, you should fix that with something like `colnames(df) <- make.names(colnames(df))`.

Comment: Not duplicate column names. I have duplicate row names. Exactly in my improved example.